# Wiring up a AAA power toy to Pinball lighting supply

Tags: ac, dc

I'm trying to wire up a toy powered by AAA batteries (3vdc @ .09A) to the lighting circuit on a pinball machine (6vac @ 4A) and I was wondering what the best possible solution that I can keep small. I know I have to rectify it to DC Voltage but stepping it down to the 3vdc is where I'ma  bit fuzzy.
Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,
-M

Answer (score 4):

The following circuit should do what you need:

[image]

It is based on the [LM317](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/LM317-D.PDF) linear regulator, which is not as efficient as a switching regulator but easier to use in a situation like yours.

The output voltage setting is determined by the two resistors:

$$V_{OUT} = 1.25V \times (1 + \frac{R2}{R1}) = 1.25V \times (1 + \frac{390}{270}) = 3.05\,V$$

Using a full wave bridge rectifier made up of [1N4007](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/1N4001-1N4007%28DO-41%29.pdf) diodes (any of the 1N400x series will do), the 6V DC coming in is rectified to a level of 6V * 1.414 = 8.5V.  Less two diode drops of at least 0.75V each, the input to the regulator will be about 7.0V or a little less.  The power dissipated in the LM317 will thus be:

$$(7.0V - 3.0V) \times 0.090\,A = 0.36\,W$$

or 360 mW.  You should not need a heat sink since this is less than a watt.

The LM317 and 1N400x series diodes are available at Digi-Key, and also RadioShack stores.

Comment: Good circuit, but is it correct to describe the LM317 as 'low dropout'? The datasheet you linked shows it needs at least 1.5 V from input to output at room temperature.

Comment: @nekomatic Point taken.  On Semiconductor calls them an LDO in the Product Description [on this page](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=LM317) but I agree with you the specs say otherwise.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a voltage regulator after a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor. The voltage regulator only has to supply 0.09 amps so it *can* be linear but with 6VAC rectified, the DC level into the regulator is about 7.5 volts. This means 4.5 volts lost in the regulator to produce 3V on the output and therefore a power dissipation of about 400mW. If this makes the heat-sinking on the regulator too big then consider using a small buck regulator.